# Debug Xamarin Bound iOS Library

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Is there a way to debug the Objective C code of a static library bound to a Xamarin iOS project?

We have non-trivial code in the objective-c view controllers, that we would like to keep (using C# to provide the underlying data&handler). So debugging capabilities are highly necessary. Of course, I think in the long term the real/proper solution is to rewrite those controllers in C# (just keeping the .xib in xcode). We are far from there.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://www.razum.si/automagical/

Comment: Even if we used something like automagical for converting the code, we would be looking at several weeks, possible couple of months of having to live with the iOS code.